# Finding all objects with Max value in a property within an Array of Objects and return values of other property from the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I know there are similar questions here, but with those methods only one max value is returned. What I need is to determine which objects of the array have that max value in a given property and return the value of a certain *(other)* property within those objects that have the max value in the given property. 
I have this array of objects called ***week*** with two properties *"name"* and *"traffic"* :

```
[
 { name: "Saturday", traffic: 12 },
 { name: "Sunday", traffic: 12 },
 { name: "Monday", traffic: 13 },
 { name: "Tuesday", traffic: 9 },
 { name: "Wednesday", traffic: 10 },
 { name: "Thursday", traffic: 8 },
 { name: "Friday", traffic: 13 },
]
```

​
In this case ***Monday*** and ***Friday*** have the max value for the property ***"Traffic"*** which is ***13*** and I need a way to return a *string* containing the name of the day with highest ***"Traffic"*** *value* if there is only one day, and an array containing the names *(as strings)* of the days that have highest ***"Traffic"*** *value* if there are more than one day with highest ***"Traffic"*** *value*, as in this case would return an array containing *Monday* and *Friday*.

I have tried this:

```
function getMaxTr() {
    return week.reduce((max, p) => p.traffic > max ? 
      p.traffic : max, week[0].traffic); 
}
```

But with this I only got one max value of the property *"traffic"* which is ***13***. 
 
And this:

```
let max = week [week.length - 1];
```

With this last one I get one object which has the max traffic value, like this: 
 
*Object { name: "Friday", traffic: 13 }*

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you want to return the `name` of the objects with max `traffic` value, you can use a combination of **[`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter)**, **[`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** and **[`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map)** methods like this:

```
let maxTraffic = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.traffic > b.traffic ? a.traffic : b.traffic;
});
var result = arr.filter(a => a.traffic == maxTraffic).map(a => a.name);
```

This will return an `array` containing the names of elements with max `traffic` value.

**Demo:**

This is a working demo:

```js
var arr = [
 { name: "Saturday", traffic: 12 },
 { name: "Sunday", traffic: 12 },
 { name: "Monday", traffic: 13 },
 { name: "Tuesday", traffic: 9 },
 { name: "Wednesday", traffic: 10 },
 { name: "Thursday", traffic: 8 },
 { name: "Friday", traffic: 13 },
];

let maxTraffic = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.traffic > b.traffic ? a.traffic : b.traffic;
});
var result = arr.filter(a => a.traffic == maxTraffic).map(a => a.name);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use reduce. In every iteration, check if there's either an element with a lower or an equal `traffic` property in your result, if so either replace the whole thing for the former case, or add the equal element to your result. If none of above returns true, simply return the last iteration's element again.

```js
const arr = [
    { name: "Saturday", traffic: 12 },
    { name: "Sunday", traffic: 12 },
    { name: "Monday", traffic: 13 },
    { name: "Tuesday", traffic: 9 },
    { name: "Wednesday", traffic: 10 },
    { name: "Thursday", traffic: 8 },
    { name: "Friday", traffic: 13 },
];

let res = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    let now = a.pop();
    if (now.traffic < b.traffic) return [b];
    if (now.traffic === b.traffic) return [...a, now, b];
    return [...a, now];
}, [arr[0]]).map(e => e.name);

res = res.length > 1 ? res : res[0];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Probably the best algorithm, but `a few checks and return the right thing` is *not* an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `reduce` to group the days and the function `pop` in case the reduce array contains only one element.

```js
var array = [ { name: "Saturday", traffic: 12 }, { name: "Sunday", traffic: 12 }, { name: "Monday", traffic: 13 }, { name: "Tuesday", traffic: 9 }, { name: "Wednesday", traffic: 10 }, { name: "Thursday", traffic: 8 }, { name: "Friday", traffic: 13 }],
    reduced = array.reduce((a, {name, traffic}) => {
      if (traffic > a.highest) {
        a.current = [name];    
        a.highest = traffic;    
      } else if (traffic === a.highest) a.current.push(name);
  
      return a;
    }, {highest: 0, current: []}).current,
    result = reduced.length === 1 ? reduced.pop() : reduced;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This code snippet shows the result as String when the sample contains only one object with the highest traffic value:

```js
var array = [ { name: "Saturday", traffic: 12 }, { name: "Sunday", traffic: 12 }, { name: "Monday", traffic: 1 }, { name: "Tuesday", traffic: 9 }, { name: "Wednesday", traffic: 10 }, { name: "Thursday", traffic: 8 }, { name: "Friday", traffic: 13 }],
    reduced = array.reduce((a, {name, traffic}) => {
      if (traffic > a.highest) {
        a.current = [name];    
        a.highest = traffic;    
      } else if (traffic === a.highest) a.current.push(name);
  
      return a;
    }, {highest: 0, current: []}).current,
    result = reduced.length === 1 ? reduced.pop() : reduced;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```